# Save Checkbox value in Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I cannot seem to save the value of a checkbox in a plugin I am creating. When I uncheck it and click Save Settings, it reverts to being checked again.
I'm not sure where I have gone wrong. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
//Global Variable
$options = array();

//Options Page
    function iwmp_options_page() {

        if( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
            wp_die('You do not have sufficient permission to access this page.');
        }

        global $options;

        if( isset($_POST['iwmp_settings_form_submitted']) ) {

            $hidden_field = esc_html( $_POST['iwmp_settings_form_submitted'] );

            if($hidden_field == "Y") {

                $iwmp_single_images = esc_html( $POST['iwmp_single_images'] );

                $options['iwmp_single_images'] = $iwmp_single_images;

                update_option('iwmp_settings', $options);

            }

        }

        $options = get_option('iwmp_settings');

        if( $options != '' ) {

            $iwmp_single_images = $options['iwmp_single_images'];

        }

        require('plugin-settings-page-wrapper.php');

    }
```

Inside the 'plugin-settings-page-wrapper.php' file: (Stripped down of course)

```
<label for="iwmp_single_images">Enable on Single Images:
  <input checked="checked" name="iwmp_single_images" type="checkbox" id="iwmp_single_images" value="1" <? checked( $options['iwmp_single_images'], 1, false );?> />
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a checkbox is unchecked, it doesn't get submitted with the form values. So when using checkboxes, you should have an `else` statement for `isset( $_POST['iwmp_settings_form_submitted'] )` and it basically will be triggered when the checkbox is unchecked. Here's the fixed code.

```
//Global Variable
$options = array();

//Options Page
function iwmp_options_page() {

    if( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        wp_die( 'You do not have sufficient permission to access this page.' );
    }

    global $options;

    // Make sure this is a POST request
    if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['_iwmp_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_iwmp_nonce'], 'iwmp_settings_nonce' ) ) {
            wp_die( 'Cheating, Huh?' );
        }

        if( isset($_POST['iwmp_settings_form_submitted']) ) {

            $hidden_field = esc_html( $_POST['iwmp_settings_form_submitted'] );

            if($hidden_field == "Y") {

                if ( isset( $_POST['iwmp_single_images'] ) ) {
                    $options['iwmp_single_images'] = esc_html( $_POST['iwmp_single_images'] );
                } else {
                    $options['iwmp_single_images'] = '';
                }

                update_option('iwmp_settings', $options);

            }

        }

    }

    $options = get_option('iwmp_settings');

    if( $options != '' ) {

        $iwmp_single_images = $options['iwmp_single_images'];

    }

    require('plugin-settings-page-wrapper.php');

}
```

I also added a nonce validation in your code(because they're a good practice). In addition to the extra code below, you should also add the following code inside of your `<form>` in your settings page HTML:

`<?php wp_nonce_field( 'iwmp_settings_nonce', '_iwmp_nonce' ); ?>`

Using nonces is a good practice that makes your plugin more secure. You can read more on Nonces here: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces

And the code for your checkbox should be as follows:

`<input name="iwmp_single_images" type="checkbox" id="iwmp_single_images" value="1" <?php checked( $options['iwmp_single_images'], 1 ); ?> />`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @Nikola Ivanov Nikolov said you shouldn't be formatting your input like this:

```
 <input checked="checked">
```

Basically, what you've done, you've made the checkbox be always checked (notice the `checked="checked"` value).

Instead, you should be using:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="iwmp_single_images" value="1" <?php checked( $options['iwmp_single_images'], 1 ); ?> />
```

Comment: Removed checked="checked" thank you. Still not saving though I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I got work like below code:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="new_option_name" value="1" <?php checked( esc_attr( get_option('new_option_name')), 1 );?> /></td>
```

Hope this will help you..